# Client ID and/or User ID - which to use?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

> Background of my specific environment: I am trying to set up GA to track the user journeys around an iOS native app written in React Native. The app is in-house only and all users consent to being tracked in this way.

As I understand it, the measurement protocol allows either Client ID (`cid`) or User ID (`uid`). In the docs, both are optional, but at least one is required. Makes sense so far. Client ID is an anonymous UUIDv4 that tracks a browser or device, but not necessarily a user. User ID on the other hand is some uniquely-identifying value for a user, but may cross devices/browsers.

Initially I wrote my application using `cid` (as I hadn't yet read the docs on `uid`). Every time a user logged in the user's uuid would be stored and sent as the `cid` parameter. I also used session control `sc`. This worked - I saw sessions coming in, the User Explorer showed me the individual user uuids and sessions, etc. But upon rereading the docs, this seemed like an incorrect use of `cid`. It seems like `cid` is meant to be consistent and not something that changes as you log in and out.

As people on my app can log in and out (and possibly will - staff members may well share devices), using a long-lasting `cid` that is specific to the device won't allow me to track the habits of individual users and changing it per login-session, as mentioned above, feels wrong.

So I switched out `cid` for `uid`. The docs say both are optional and one is only required if the other is not used, so I figured I could just use `uid` and use the user's uuid in that field and it's otherwise act the same.

However, when doing it this way no hits seems to be registered at all - in "real time data" as well as the User Explorer.

Am I doing something wrong or is this by design? (If by design, are the docs wrong to say `cid` and `uid` are both optional or am I reading it incorrectly?)

Either way, best-practices-wise, do I:

- Just go back to using an ephemeral `cid` that only changes when people log in and out. Individual sessions in the app don't change the cid but I do use `sc` to explicitly start and end sessions by navigation inference (click 'home' = `sc=end`, navigate from 'home', `sc=start`).
- Use `uid` as I am trying to (i.e. switching out the current `cid` for `uid`), but also include a random `cid` that never changes (regardless of session lifetime, logging in and out, etc.).
- Something else?

---

I have seen [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352129/userid-cid-in-measurement-protocol) but it does not really answer my actual question regarding how `cid` and `uid` should *actually* be used, and if my issue is me or the way that GA works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oki so client-id is randomly generated value and must be sent with all hits. 
In a non-User-ID-enabled view, Client-ID is used to calculate unique users. In a User-ID-enabled view, User-ID is used to calculate unique users

In reference to your app, *you can send the unique `Device id` value in place of random value for client-id*. This will resolve all your problems and e**nsure that the client id is sent with all the hits, otherwise it wont get registered in GA**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have since discovered than I am an idiot and just wasn't looking at a user-enabled view, hence not seeing any hits arriving. As such, the way I was using it was actually working, I just didn't know it. Regarding the Device ID, I was under the impression that that wasn't advised unless the user is able to reset their device ID, as it could constitute (at least a precursor to) PII for Google. Anyway, I'll accept your answer as you point out that a user enabled view is what works with the User ID, which is really the info I needed.

Comment: device id can be sent as client id but u can always hash it. Happy to help always :)